# How can a TrueCrypt hidden volume of greater than 2 TB be created?

Tags: external-hdd, truecrypt

I want to create a hidden TrueCrypt volume within an 8 TB USB drive. When I try to format in order to create the outer volume, I am presented with the following message:

```
Error: The hidden volume to be created is larger than 2 TB (2048 GB).

Possible solutions:
- Create a container/partition smaller than 2 TB.
- Use a drive with 4096-byte sectors to be able to create partition/device-hosted hidden volumes up to 16 TB in size.
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I have previously encrypted a 4 TB drive successfully with TrueCrypt, so the first option does not make sense to me. I do not know how to think about the second option; if it means buying a new hard drive, then that is not a realistic suggestion.

What should I do?

Comment: You should do any of the two options listed in that message. If you decided on one please [edit] your question to clarify what you need help with.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have added the text as requested, but note that good screen-readers for those who are vision-impaired or good image-to-text converters for site metadata can handle images of text.

Comment: That's certainly true but afaik StackExchange doesn't run OCR over posted images. Also, I tend to skip questions that require me to transcribe error messages from images before I can look them up in a search engine.

Comment: Truecrypt is an unmaintained project with rather questionable source and licensing. Please try Veracrypt, the successor of Truecrypt, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GPT for partitions larger than 2Tb. Booting such a partition it is not supported.

MBR has a limit of 2TB.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This is an external drive; am not seeking to boot from it.

Comment: @d3pd what don't you understand? 1. external disk can be booted from too if you would want to. 2. you can not boot from a GPT encrypted disk with more than 2Tb. If you don't want that then there is no problem for you. Just saying that if you'd want to (cuz someone else might) you can't